# SwiftUI/Combine: FetchedResults Error Accessing StateObject's object without being installed on a View

Tags: xcode, core-data, swiftui, combine

I'm trying to create an `CoreData` `Entity` observer:

```
@FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: []) var todoResult: FetchedResults<Todo>
    
    init() {
        todoResult.publisher.sink { _ in
            print("sink")
        } receiveValue: { todos in
            print("recoved todos")
        }.store(in: &cancellables)
}
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
Accessing StateObject's object without being installed on a View. This will create a new instance each time.
```

[image]

Any of you knows why I'm getting this error since I'm not creating this instance in a model? or if you know a work around this error. I'll really appreciated.

Comment: Why are you trying to set a publisher to a `CoreData Entity`which is already an `ObservableObject`? That is the root of your error message.

Comment: The behavior of FetchRequest is the same as State and StateObject, their internal are absent at initialisation phase and become available only inside body. To do what you want you can instantiate FetchRequest manually, like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/60761630/12299030 or in https://stackoverflow.com/a/59169794/12299030. Alternate is to create subview in body with injected todoResult, so todoResult will be already fetched and valid in that subview init.

Comment: All CoreData objects are `ObservableObject`s, just wrap each `Todo` in `@ObservedObject` in the SwiftUI `View` that needs/makes the changes. BTW it looks like you are trying to use `@FetchRequest` in a class` use `NSFetchRequest` or `NSFetchedResultsController`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `@FetchRequest` inside a `View` struct.

The reason for the error that `@StateObject` must also be used inside a View struct is because the `FetchRequest` struct declares an `@StateObject` inside it, which is the delegate for the `NSFetchedResultsController` it uses.

In SwiftUI these dynamic properties/property wrappers give reference type semantics to the View struct value types so you don't need to use actual objects. SwiftUI calls update on these dynamic properties before body is run, which is how `FetchRequest` can retrieve the managed object context from the environment.

Also FYI when we do create an `ObservableObject` it's usually to hold our model struct array. If we use Combine inside one then we never use `sink` or `cancellables`, instead we `assign` the end of the pipeline to an `@Published`.

Comment: I add it `@Published internal var todo:[Todo] = []`  and this `todoResult.publisher.assign(to: \.todo, on: self).store(in: &cancellables)` in the init but I'm getting this error `Key path value type '[Todo]' cannot be converted to contextual type 'Publishers.Sequence<FetchedResults<Todo>, Never>.Output' (aka 'Todo')`